# PHP setting var to only a portion of a string

Tags: php, mysql, var

I have a panel I'm making that will use session data from another forum to give it permissions.  Basically when the user logs into our forum and the session and trust is created on the forum, they can click on the panel and the panel will check their browser cookie for the session id and trust id.  It then takes that trust id and checks the forum's database for the user id associated with that trust.  Then takes the session id and verifies that it belongs to that user id.  The issue is that when I get the session id, the associated user id is part of a blob that i have to cast in order to get the data from the field.  So I get a result like this:

```
('7c64c90413beb7d139c64ccc8b13380b', 
'a:12:{s:12:"sessionStart";i:1454075264;s:2:"ip";s:4:"b???";s:11:"sessionCsrf";s:16:"-2Yx13nBLdstUj4H";

s:7:"user_id";i:20;

s:13:"password_date";i:1453353041;s:16:"previousActivity";i:1454072099;s:13:"trophyChecked";b:1;s:16:"promotionChecked";b:1;s:16:"dismissedNotices";a:0:{}s:15:"lastNoticeReset";i:0;s:13:"canAdminUsers";b:1;s:20:"userModerationCounts";a:2:{s:5:"total";i:0;s:13:"lastBuildDate";i:1454075264;}}'),
```

I know there is a lot there, but I singled out the part that matters to me.  The first column returned is the session id, which im using to verify the user id, but the user id is in the middle of that all that crap in the second column.  So you can see where I single out the definition, what I want to do is just assign that "20" after "user_id;i:" to a variable and discard the rest.  I'm sure this is simply done, but at this point I think I'm just nuking it out and spinning wheels.  I was thinking explode, but the structure of that data seems like that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is simply the result of a PHP [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) call. You can pass it to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), which will provide you with an array containing the values.

```
<?php

$str = 'a:12:{s:12:"sessionStart"…etc…etc…i:1454075264;}}';

$arr = unserialize($str);

var_dump($arr['user_id']);
```

In case you’re trying to extract the value from within MySQL alone, for some reason I’ve done something similar with an awful query containing lots of nested `SUBSTR()` and `LOCATE()` just two weeks ago. I wouldn’t recommend it. Especially because in my case I was doing a one-off reporting query, while you’re trying to do authentication with it. People might try to use specially crafted cookies to circumvent your string extraction and gain illegitimate access.

Comment: well, that data is coming straight from the query, I"m not using any php yet, that's what I get when I run a query on the database.

Comment: so will it return an associated array?  ie: var["user_id"] would equal 20?

Comment: Sorry, it didn’t become quite clear from your question that you’re not using PHP to access the data. Yes, it will return an associative array. I’ve added a code example and talked a bit about how (not) to do it in MySQL alone.